# How to examine the real-time queue capacity of BoundedElasticScheduler in reactor-core library

Tags: project-reactor

I'm using **reactor-core** in my project and use **BoundedElasticScheduler** for multi-threading. As we know the scheduler has a queue to hold the tasks when all threads are busy. And we can give it a cap value when initializing the scheduler.

Now I want to monitor the queue size and take action in case the queue is almost full, which means the traffic is getting higher.

The queue actually has an `estimateRemainingTaskCapacity()` method to get the remaining capacity, while it's not exposed.

Is there any way to achieve this?